# How to initialize numpy 2D array with different values for each strip

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I want to initialize 2D numpy array with 2 for the strip for which the column is smaller than row + x (x is a parameter) and with 3 for the strip for which the column is larger than row + y (assume y > x) like this:

[image]

Is there a way which is more fast than brute force nested loops:

```
pos_path = np.zeros((rows + 1, cols + 1), dtype=np.int32)
rows = 384;
cols = 288;
x = -12
y = 23
for r in range(0, rows+1):
    for c in range(0, cols + 1):
        if c < r + x:
             pos_path[r, c] = 2
        elif c > r + y:
             pos_path[r, c] = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simply use the ranged-arrays with outer-operations to get the equivalent masks and then use those to assign the relevant values in the output in a vectorized manner, like so -

```
pos_path_out = np.zeros((rows + 1, cols + 1), dtype=np.int32)
R = np.arange(0, rows+1)
C = np.arange(0, cols+1)
m1 = C < R[:,None] + x
m2 = C > R[:,None] + y
pos_path_out[m1] = 2
pos_path_out[m2] = 3
```

Alternatively, we can directly setup the output array off `m1` and then assign for `m2` -

```
pos_path_out = m1*2
pos_path_out[m2] = 3
```

Or get the final output off `m1` and `m2` in one go -

```
pos_path_out = m1*2+m2*3
```

For large arrays, leverage multi-cores with `numexpr` -

```
import numexpr as ne

pos_path_out = ne.evaluate('(C < R2D + x)*2 + (C >R2D + y)*3',{'R2D':R[:,None]})
```

---

Another one making use of the ramp nature of the masks, we could create those masks with ranged-outer-comparison -

```
pos_path_out = np.zeros((rows + 1, cols + 1), dtype=np.int32)
ra = np.arange(cols+1)
p1 = np.arange(y,rows+y+1)
p2 = np.arange(x,rows+x+1)
m1 = p1[:,None]<ra
m2 = p2[:,None]>ra
np.putmask(pos_path_out,m1,3)
np.putmask(pos_path_out,m2,2)
```

Or use `np.tri` to create those masks -

```
m1 = ~np.tri(rows+1,cols+1,k=y, dtype=bool)
m2 = np.tri(rows+1,cols+1,k=x-1, dtype=bool)
```